# how to send the user to another page by attaching some jquery code to the url in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send the user to another page when clicking on a specified button.
I would like to add some jquery values to the URL beside sending the user to another page but everychange I try adding the jquery to the url I can't do what I want.
I tried using . for connecting url to jquery but it doesn't work.
how is it possible?

below is my code for this purpose:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('tr').hover(function(){
    if($(this).index() != 0)
      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
});
$('tr').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','');
});
$('tr').click(function(){
        alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()) );
        //window.location.replace ="con_sodur_card.php?id="$(this).index();
        **$(location).attr('href', 'con_sodur_card.php?id="$(this).index()"')**
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to evaluate the expression first, then concatenate it with your desired url string.

```
var myIndex = $(this).index();
var newURL = "/con_sodur_card.php?id=" + myIndex;
window.location.href = newURL;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

var url = 'con_sodur_card.php';
window.location.href = url;